# How multiple OpenGL views share single GL_RENDERBUFFER in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-animation, eaglcontext, caeagllayer

Let's say I have two views need to present the same OpenGL content in renderBuffer. How do I bind this two view's `CAEAGLLayer` to the renderBuffer?`renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:` just bind the last `CAEAGLLayer` to `GL_RENDEARBUFFER`.

Comment: My iOS knowledge is limited. But couldn't you just use two framebuffers and bind each view to each renderbuffer of those framebuffers.

Comment: In my situation, there are more than two views need to present the same OpenGL's content. If each view's layer separately bind to renderBuffer, I think there are some unnecessary memory and GPU footprint.